# GCC linker do not remove unused function. If unsing a template, it works

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, linker

I have a question. :)

My demo source call a mmemberfunction of a class. In my case, the function returns every time integer 4.
If I switch on optimisation -O2, the function call is optimize out. A "constant" 4 is use.
This is, what what i expect.

But: In binary I found the (now with optimisation) unused function.

```
#include <iostream>

class Converter {
public:
    virtual uint32_t convert(uint32_t x) {
        return x * 2;
    }
};

class Filter {
public:
    explicit Filter(Converter& converter) : 
        m_converter(converter)
    {}

    uint32_t doWork(uint32_t x) {
        return m_converter.convert(x);
    }
private:
    Converter& m_converter;
};
    
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Converter converter;

    Filter            filter(converter);

    return filter.doWork(2);
}
```

godbolt output

```
   Converter::convert(unsigned long):
      lsl     r0, r1, #1
      bx      lr
   main:
      mov     r0, #4           <- 4 is use, no function call
      bx      lr
```

Compiler options:
-O2 -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -Wl,--gc-sections

Compiler:
ARM GCC 10.2.1  (NONE)

I try this on my windows PC with MinGW.
The result is the same. (inspect the EXE file with objdump)

I figure out, that the linker remove the function, when     Filter     is a template class

```
#include <iostream>

class Converter {
public:
    virtual uint32_t convert(uint32_t x) {
        return x * 2;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class Filter1 {
public:
    explicit Filter1(T converter) : 
        m_converter(converter)
    {}

    uint32_t doWork(uint32_t x) {
        return m_converter.convert(x);
    }
private:
    T m_converter;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Converter converter;

    Filter1<Converter> filter(converter);

    return filter.doWork(2);
}
```

godbolt output

```
main:
    mov     r0, #4
    bx      lr
```

Why do not remove the linker the function, if I do not use a template class?

[Here is the godbolt link to the source](https://godbolt.org/z/ffsEY7)

Comment: addition: optimizing for size -Os do not solve the problem

Comment: Do you need the function to be `virtual`?

Comment: Oh, ok. No I do not neet it virtual in the sample. In real Code i need it virtual. Wy can't optimaze the function, if it is virtual?